# How does holographic voxel density scale with holographic film metrics?

Tags: optics, geometry, hologram

I'm trying to understand how one can generate bounds on the effective number of voxels (volumetric pixels) in a hologram, or information density, provided various metrics for the two-dimensional holographic film being used.  For example, I often come across film parameters for grain size, resolving power (usually referred to in terms of lines/mm), and emulsion thickness.  Is there a straightforward way to calculate this, or perhaps good rules of thumb?

Answer (score 1):

Holographic voxels cannot just simply be put into a film(Unless you use a decoder for sendimg information to a computer). It however can put into a file.
The file size will be the same regardless of the density(You meant opacity rigth?) of the voxel, it is saved in the file as a parameter. 
About the calculation part, it depends on how the voxel-based 3D image software saves their files.